# How to Pass # in url in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, url, drupal-6

i am using Drupal while creating page i need to set automatic alias to residentialprojects#Floors what when i click the page it shows residentialprojects%2523Floors

but i need # only

Can anyboy have idea about this ?

thanks

Comment: use `html_enity_decode()` to see original string

Comment: he is using drupal you can't pass html_enity_decode()

Comment: If your alias is "residentialprojects#Floors" and if you go to http://example.com/residentialprojects#Floors , you will end in http://example.com/residentialprojects - isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below lines of code:

```
function drupal_urlencode($text) {
  if (variable_get('clean_url', '0')) {
    return str_replace(array('%2F', '%3F', '%3D', '%26', '%2523'),
                       array('/', '?', '=', '&', '#'),
                       urlencode($text));
  }
  else {
    return str_replace('%2F', '/', urlencode($text));
  }
}
```

I think it would be working fine for you. Please check it.

Thanks.